# JUnit5 test case on Repository class

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, junit, mockito

I am writing JUnit test cases for the repository layer.

I am working on a spring boot gradle project.

using the H2 in-memory database for the test cases.

**This is my Repository layer test cases**

```
@DataJpaTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles(Constant.TEST_PROFILE)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
class TopicRepositoryTest {
  @Autowired TopicRepository topicRepository;
  @Autowired DomainRepository domainRepository;

  private Topic topic;
  private Domain domain;

  @BeforeEach
  void addTestRecord() {
    domain = createDomain();
    topic = createTopic();
  }

  private Topic createTopic() {
    Topic topic = new Topic();
    topic.setId(1);
    topic.setName("Java");
    topic.setUid("35f66eaa-2fc7-4170-8470-feb83ddbf6b0");
    Domain domain = new Domain();
    domain.setId(1);
    domain.setName("Java");
    domain.setUid("1234z637-c6c1-4dc3-9755-9f6ad974d70b");
    topic.setDomain(domain);
    return topic;
  }

  private Domain createDomain() {
    Domain domain = new Domain();
    domain.setId(1);
    domain.setName("Java");
    domain.setUid("1234z637-c6c1-4dc3-9755-9f6ad974d70b");
    return domain;
  }

  @Test
  void findAllTopicByDomainId() {
    domainRepository.save(domain);
    topicRepository.save(topic);
    final var result =
        topicRepository.findAllTopicByDomainId("1234z637-c6c1-4dc3-9755-9f6ad974d70b");
    assertEquals(1, result.size());
    assertEquals("Java", result.get(0).getName());
  }

  @Test
  void deleteByUid() {
    domainRepository.save(domain);
    topicRepository.save(topic);
    assertTrue(topicRepository.findById(topic.getId()).isPresent());
    topicRepository.deleteByUid(topic.getUid());
    assertFalse(topicRepository.findById(topic.getId()).isPresent());
  }

  @Test
  void getTopicByUid() {
    domainRepository.save(domain);
    topicRepository.save(topic);
    final var result = topicRepository.getTopicByUid(topic.getUid());
    assertEquals("Java", result.getName());
  }
}
```

**AND this is my Domain.class**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Domain {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  private String uid;
}
```

when I run all test cases manually they execute successfully

and if I run TopicRepositoryTest.class I am facing this error.

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists domain cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists topic cascade 
Hibernate: create table domain (id integer generated by default as identity, name varchar(255), uid varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table topic (id integer generated by default as identity, name varchar(255), uid varchar(255), domain_id integer, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table if exists topic add constraint FKdg7t6kdm25v4v8ekv96mlcm1l foreign key (domain_id) references domain
2023-05-03T18:04:21.764+05:30  INFO 24738 --- [    Test worker] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-05-03T18:04:21.773+05:30  INFO 24738 --- [    Test worker] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-03T18:04:22.125+05:30  WARN 24738 --- [    Test worker] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: com.testiqo.exam.engine.repository.TopicRepository
2023-05-03T18:04:22.476+05:30  WARN 24738 --- [    Test worker] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: com.testiqo.exam.engine.repository.DomainRepository
2023-05-03T18:04:22.538+05:30  INFO 24738 --- [    Test worker] c.t.e.e.repository.TopicRepositoryTest   : Started TopicRepositoryTest in 4.103 seconds (process running for 5.541)
Hibernate: select d1_0.id,d1_0.name,d1_0.uid from domain d1_0 where d1_0.id=?
Hibernate: insert into domain (id, name, uid) values (default, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select t1_0.id,d1_0.id,d1_0.name,d1_0.uid,t1_0.name,t1_0.uid from topic t1_0 left join domain d1_0 on d1_0.id=t1_0.domain_id where t1_0.id=?
Hibernate: insert into topic (id, domain_id, name, uid) values (default, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select t1_0.id,t1_0.domain_id,t1_0.name,t1_0.uid from topic t1_0 where t1_0.uid=?
Hibernate: select d1_0.id,d1_0.name,d1_0.uid from domain d1_0 where d1_0.id=?
Hibernate: insert into domain (id, name, uid) values (default, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select t1_0.id,d1_0.id,d1_0.name,d1_0.uid,t1_0.name,t1_0.uid from topic t1_0 left join domain d1_0 on d1_0.id=t1_0.domain_id where t1_0.id=?
Hibernate: select d1_0.id,d1_0.name,d1_0.uid from domain d1_0 where d1_0.id=?

Unable to find com.testiqo.exam.engine.entity.Domain with id 1
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.testiqo.exam.engine.entity.Domain with id 1
    at app//org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:376)
    at app//org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at app//org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at app//org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at app//org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:163)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
    at app/jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy115.save(Unknown Source)
    at app//com.testiqo.exam.engine.repository.TopicRepositoryTest.setUp(TopicRepositoryTest.java:107)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeEachMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:78)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeMethodInExtensionContext(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:520)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$synthesizeBeforeEachMethodAdapter$23(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:505)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeEachMethods$3(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:174)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeMethodsOrCallbacksUntilExceptionOccurs(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeEachMethods(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:134)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.testiqo.exam.engine.entity.Domain with id 1
    at app//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:182)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:228)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:358)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:110)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:72)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118)
    at app//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1244)
    at app//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1097)
    at app//org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:653)
    at app//org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:396)
    at app//org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:314)
    at app//org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:143)
    at app//org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:154)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:531)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:247)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:356)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:178)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:81)
    at app//org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at app//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:830)
    at app//org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:816)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311)
    at app/jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy107.merge(Unknown Source)
    at app//org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:616)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168)
    at app//org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at app//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
    at app//org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at app//org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 96 more

Hibernate: select d1_0.id,d1_0.name,d1_0.uid from domain d1_0 where d1_0.id=?
Hibernate: insert into domain (id, name, uid) values (default, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select t1_0.id,d1_0.id,d1_0.name,d1_0.uid,t1_0.name,t1_0.uid from topic t1_0 left join domain d1_0 on d1_0.id=t1_0.domain_id where t1_0.id=?
Hibernate: select d1_0.id,d1_0.name,d1_0.uid from domain d1_0 where d1_0.id=?
```

**I dont know how solve this**

Comment: the  void addTestRecord() is only creating objects but not saving them in the repository

Comment: Try to add @Transactional on the class level. It might help.

Comment: still not working

Comment: could you also share the code of the "Domain" class? Also please share bigger part of stacktrace not only the last two lines.

Comment: ohk i share full error

Comment: when a first test case is executed successfully then hibernate executed select query for finding domain object with id = 1 but why? @fascynacja

Comment: Maybe you can remove "GeneratedValue",  or change the strategy to smth else? You can also try to select and print all domain values from dB in order to see what ids they really have.

Comment: but i am using H2 database for test cases only @fascynacja

Answer (score 0):

The problem here might be that while you are saving entities in the database their "id" is generated by the database. So the id which you assigned  to the *Domain* object: "1", does not really exist.
You can try to

a) after saving *Domain* into database reuse the returned entity ( which will have real id assigned)

b) remove the *Domain* creation in the *createTopic* method, instead always reuse the one which was created before

c) in your testcases do not recreate those objects again but reuse the ones created in @BeforeEach

```
@BeforeEach
void addTestRecord() {
    domain = domainRepository.save(createDomain());  //a
    System.out.println("Domain id is: " + domain.getId());
    topic = topicRepository.save(createTopic());
    System.out.println("Topic id is: " + topic.getId());
}


private Topic createTopic() {
    Topic topic = new Topic();
    topic.setId(1);
    topic.setName("Java");
    topic.setUid("35f66eaa-2fc7-4170-8470-feb83ddbf6b0");
    topic.setDomain(domain); //b
    return topic;
}

@Test
void findAllTopicByDomainId() {
    //domainRepository.save(domain); // c remove those lines
    //topicRepository.save(topic);   // c remove those lines
    final var result =
        topicRepository.findAllTopicByDomainId("1234z637-c6c1-4dc3-9755-9f6ad974d70b");
    assertEquals(1, result.size());
    assertEquals("Java", result.get(0).getName());
}
```